# Jest hangs when running in docker with some CPU / RAM config

Tags: docker, jestjs

Some days ago I upgraded my codebase from jest 26 to 27.

Running tests in my local environment worked like a charm but, when I tried to run them on my CI machine, the tests "never" stop.

Actually, in CI,  the process exited correctly when trying to run tests sequentially but not in parallel, eg with `--runInBand --detectOpenHandles --forceExit`.

I tried to build and run the same docker locally... and it worked.

Changing randomly some docker's CPU / RAM configs, I achieved the same result: the process hangs.

[image: docker config]

Tests hanging:
[image: tests hanging]

Running `top` in docker:
[image: docker top]

As you can see, it's not a problem of CPU / RAM considering what `top` says.

Do you have any hints?

Do you need more information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some days debugging, I figured out that the problem was the amount of RAM and some memory leaks in the tests.

I advise you to use the `node --expose-gc ./node_modules/.bin/jest --logHeapUsage` command to dive into the problems you can have. https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--logheapusage

This post helped me out as well: https://chanind.github.io/javascript/2019/10/12/jest-tests-memory-leak.html

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR:**

I fixed memory leaks by downgrading `node` from `16.13.2` to `16.10.0`.

**Details:**

Based on [Mattia Larentis answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68995616/5599567):

I had the same problem, code and tests were written for client app, used packages:

- node: 16.13.2
- jest: 27.4.7
- ts-jest: 27.1.3
- typescript: 4.5.5

After debugging and analysing jest tests, I detected memory leaks too, using:

```
node --expose-gc ./node_modules/.bin/jest --logHeapUsage
```

Then I analysed `node` heap snapshots (for more info see [Your Jest Tests are Leaking Memory)](https://chanind.github.io/javascript/2019/10/12/jest-tests-memory-leak.html).

I found a lot of strings, containing transpiled TS code.

I went to ts-jest & jest repos to look for issues about memory leaks.

I found these:

- ts-jest: [Module caching memory leak](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/1967)
- jest: [[Bug]: Memory consumption issues on Node JS 16.11.0+](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/11956)
- node: [vm Script memory leak in Node.js 14 / 16](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/40014)

Then, I downgraded `node` version from `16.13.2` to `16.10.0`, checked memory leaks using

```
node --expose-gc ./node_modules/.bin/jest --logHeapUsage
```

And found that problem was gone.